# How to temporary disable click event on a HTML element

Tags: jquery

```
 $(function(){
   $(".first").click(function(){ 
               $(".first ul li").slideUp();
               $(this).find("li").slideDown();        
   });
});
```

How can I make the active `.first` element temporary unclickable until its class siblings are referred as active and of course executing the code above is necessary.

Also no matter what type it is: `div`, `li`.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By active, do you mean they have a class called `active`?

If so, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".first").click(function() {
        if( $( this ).siblings( ':not(.active)' ).length === 0 ) {
             $(".first ul li").slideUp();
             $(this).find("li").slideDown(); 
        }       
    });
});
```

When the element with the `.first` class is clicked, it simply gets [its `.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) that [do `:not()` have](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) the active class, and checks the quantity it found using [the `length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

When the `length` is `0`, they all have the `active` class.

Comment: No, by active I mean that they are clicked but anyway appending class should work either!

Comment: @user - Yes, there should be some way to indicate that they have been clicked. Adding an `active` class is an easy way to do it, plus you can use that class to apply some style in order to give the user a visual cue that it has been clicked (if necessary).

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Bad case of Monday sloppy code. Thanks to [Peter Ajtai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186636/peter-ajtai) for picking up on that (see comments).

```
 $(function(){
   $(".first").click(function(event){

               
               if ($(this).siblings('.active').length !== $(this).siblings().length) {
                   return false;
               }
 
               $(".first ul li").slideUp();
               $(this).find("li").slideDown();        
   });
});
```

So if all the siblings don't have an `active` class, then your function will bail out early.

Comment: Why not just `if( $(this).siblings(".active").length !== siblings.length)`?

Comment: I guess I should append this "active" class to the element, right?
And that "function(event)" thing makes the function Boolean type or?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .unbind() and then .bind() the event again. But I think the class toggling is more efficient.